# Adding two given floating point numbers in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point

How would I create a method with Python to add floating point numbers that are in a list, without using libraries?. The teacher gave us this code, and I didn't understand it, could anyone else give me another example?

```
def msum(iterable):
    "Full precision summation using multiple floats for intermediate values"
    partials = []               # sorted, non-overlapping partial sums
    for x in iterable:
        i = 0
        for y in partials:
            if abs(x) < abs(y):
                x, y = y, x
            hi = x + y
            lo = y - (hi - x)
            if lo:
                partials[i] = lo
                i += 1
            x = hi
        partials[i:] = [x]
    return sum(partials, 0.0)
```

Comment: Your code seems to be the implementation of [Kahan algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)

Comment: Something has to be said for meaningful variable names.

Comment: Your code will never do anything useful as partials is empty.  Perhaps your indentation is off?

Comment: Well, not just that, but `partials` doesn't get appended to at any point (`partials[i] = lo` will fail the first time it's called). This code is a huge mess...is it supposed to even work?

Comment: a broken one of course... it does nothing and returns always `None`

Comment: @aland: No, it's not an implementation of the Kahan algorithm, thought it's not unrelated.  It's taken directly from the comments of mathmodule.c in the python source, and gives a pure Python version of math.fsum.  See http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6892ce7e56f/Modules/mathmodule.c#l1030 and http://bugs.python.org/issue2819.

Comment: @sberry:  Yep, looks like something mangled the indentation.  Fixing ...

Comment: BTW, the original paper the code is based on can be found at: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/quake/public/papers/robust-arithmetic.ps  It's a little embarrassing that this isn't credited in the Python source.

Answer (score 1):

A version of the Kahan algorithm in python would look like this:

```
def msum(input):
    sum = 0.0
    c = 0.0
    for x in input:
        y = x - c
        t = sum + y
        c = (t - sum) - y
        sum = t

    return sum
```

And what does "without using other libraries" even mean?  Of course you could just have

```
def msum(input):
    return sum(input)
```

Comment: The `sum` functions uses the "naive algorithm". If you want precise floating-point sums you should use `math.fsum`.